# Unable to get option text name in controller js

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, picklist

```
<lightning:select name="levelrate" aura:id="recpickVal" class="level" label="Select Tier"  onchange="{!c.tierRateChange}">
                        <option text="--Select--" value="NONE"/>    
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.tierRates}" var="su">
                            
<option text="{!su.Tier__c}" value{!su.Charge_Rate__c}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
```

---

Here in this code I am getting the value in controller by using

```
var dataVal = event.getSource().get("v.value");
```

But here I also want the option text name in my controller.How can I get that.

Any idea how can I get the option text name.

Comment: I've linked an answer that should help you. Please let us know if you need further assistance with this problem. You can [edit] your question to provide additional details if you need more support, and we'll be glad to reopen your question for you.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox it worked for me.